# In an Android test, how to check that a View is shown?

Tags: android, unit-testing, user-interface

I'm writing a UI test case (using ActivityUnitTestCase) and would like to check if at a given time a View subclass is visible to the user. I've found the **View#isShown()** method, which claims to do exactly this - checking the visibility field of this element and all its parents - but somehow it always returns "false" for all the elements. I'll be grateful for some help. If it makes it easier, I can paste some code.

Also, I found **ViewAsserts#assertOnScreen(View origin, View view)** but it doesn't seem to do the right thing either - always returns true. Am I perhaps calling it wrong: assertOnScreen(viewImTesting.getRootView(), viewImTesting)?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Ping - Android experts - any clue? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a sensible workaround: just checking **View#getVisibility()** against **View#VISIBLE**, **VIEW#INVISIBLE**, or **VIEW#GONE**.

This probably doesn't work when e.g. a parent view is not visible but this one has visibility  set to VISIBLE, but for most cases it should suffice.

Comment: Thank you. I was using isShown() too and was getting extremely inconsistent results for a simple ImageView without any children and a clearly visible parent. This solution works much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
final View origin = activityImTesting.getWindow().getDecorView();
android.test.ViewAsserts.assertOnScreen(origin, viewImTesting);
```

Comment: Hi @dtmilano, I try to implement your solution, but `assertOnScreen()` method cannot be found. Do you have any clues why it is so?

Comment: Is in ViewAsserts class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ViewAsserts.html#assertOnScreen(android.view.View, android.view.View)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too late? Just for triggering some response from @dtmilano and other Android experts, there seems to be some differences in interpretation of visibility "gone".

While visibility=gone is [listed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#visibility) as if a view is completely not added, this [definition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) is probably closer to the truth. I realise it is actually still on the screen with a x and y coordinate, but the width and height will be 0.

And when I dig into ViewAsserts.java, assertOnScreen() is only concerned with the y coordinate  of the view in the origin, ensuring it is bigger than 0 but not more than the height of the origin.

To conclude: assertOnScreen is probably not the right method to use if you are testing for the visibility of a view, which I suppose is what you are trying to do based on your question.

Hope the above information is of use (and correct)!